# Factory Isolation Pattern with IoC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

From what I understand Factory Isolation Pattern is only required when target interface does not implement IDisposable.

1. So for the code below this would be incorrect usage, since IDbConnection does implement IDisposable. Is this correct?
2. Suppose IDbConnection did not implement IDisposable then that usage would be correct. IDbConnection would be disposed once Lambda expression finished. Correct?

   ```
   public class IsolationConnectionFactory : IConnectionIsolationFactory {
       public void With(Action<IDbConnection> do){
           using (var connecion = CreateConnection()){
               do(connection);
           }
       }
   }

   // IConnectionIsolationFactory injected by IoC in this class
   public IEnumerable<TaskDto> GetAllTasks(){
       // Usage
       connectionFactory.With(connection => {
           connection.Open();
           // get data/while read etc
       })
   }
   ```

Comment: I just came across this section in "Adaptive Code Via C#" and have the same question. What I don't get is, since factory returns an interface that does not extend `IDisposable`, the `using` block doesn't recognize `IDisposable` since it's on the class. I created an example for myself and it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FactoryIsolationPattern is introduced in "[Adaptive Code Via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735683204)". Your client code is similar to the one used to explain the usage of this pattern. The intent of the patterns as explained by author is, not to overburden classes with Disposing logic. Rather a construct is used to scope the life of the object and providing disposing unit within.

So it shouldn't affect if you have IDisposable implemented. It's like instead of context block you're using Isolated factory.

I only see problem in this block of code:

```
public void With(Action<IDbConnection> do){
    using (var connecion = CreateConnection()){
        do(connection);
    }
}
```

The pattern is provided to add disposing logic for non-disposable interfaces. But you have already placed a using over `CreateConnection()` mean this factory method should return an object that have `IDisposable` implemented. Which is against the purpose of this pattern.

Comment: So, instead of wrapping action code in using block, it is implied to use try... finally code block. And in "finally" section you test, if injected type is disposable, and dispose it if it is.

Comment: Factory Isolation Pattern seems to me a Leaky Abstraction. IMHO, it can be avoided simply intercepting/decorating GetAllTasks method. Possibly with a need of extracting it to its own interface (ISP)

Answer (score 1):

> So for the code below this would be incorrect usage, since IDbConnection does implement IDisposable. Is this correct?

I wouldn't say "incorrect usage". I would say that it is probably not needed in this case.

Sometimes however, you might want to use an isolation factory even if the product of the factory implements `IDisposable`. You may want to make sure that the consumer does not forget to dispose of the product. Or you might have some other finalization/release code other than calling `IDisposable.Dispose`.

> Suppose IDbConnection did not implement IDisposable then that usage would be correct. IDbConnection would be disposed once Lambda expression finished. Correct?

Yes.

In this case, although `IDbConnection` does not implement `IDisposable`, the return type of `CreateConnection` must implement `IDisposable` because in your code you are using the `using` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Factory Isolation (anti-)Pattern has [Abuse of Abstract Factories code smell](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-abuse-of-abstract-factories/) (unless it creates data structure). Also mind the Law of Demeter. More elegant solution is Proxy pattern.